# Defining a global variable in GoogleScript

Tags: javascript, forms, global-variables, variable-declaration

I'm working on a project where I have a google sites form that pulls data from a google CloudSQL (materials) database into a google spreadsheet, and then the form will select the appropriate info to display, depending on what part you select, to allow for editing information about an existing part. The form also allows adding a new part into the database, in which the form will add the new data to the spreadsheet which will write the new data into the CloudSQL database. *(It's probably better to cut the spreadsheet right out, and just have the form pull straight from the database, and write directly to the database, but this might be a little complex for me)*

So I have a pretty good script going, although I am very new at this stuff, I have been successful by taking an existing example on the web, and modifying a lot of it to suit my needs. Adding new or other functionality to the form is a bit of a struggle however.

In my code, I have 3 functions:

**doGet** (creates the form, and adds all the fields for part attributes - eg. name, manufacturer, cost, etc.

**goSelection** (From listbox on the form, you can select either "New" to add new part, or scroll through the list and select a partID to edit a part attribute. When you select a partID from the listbox, it populates all the form fields with the appropriate attributes of the part, which can be edited and saved (with goSave function) to update the part in the database)

**goSave** (Once you have selected New or a partID, hitting the Save button will write it to the database)

I want to create another listbox for users (to show who added or edited a part), and I was hoping to make a global variable so that I can use it in the doGet (to show it in the form), but also in goSave (If they selected a user, they must put in a password in order to Save it)

Not sure if this is even the best way to go about it, but it's kind of the direction I'm heading.

My main issue right now, is that I can't seem to declare global variables. I've looked on the internet and everywhere just says that I can define a global variable outside of a function the same way I would define a variable within a function, and that I can even drop the "var" part and it will be global.
I've tried both ways and it doesn't seem to work because the variable does not turn blue (like how it does inside my functions) and then anytime I try to reference the global variable, it's not blue either.

See image: http://postimg.org/image/vnxxgrfrl/

userSelector is blue when you declare it inside the function, but when declaring it outside of the function, it does not turn blue indicating that it's a usable variable.

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested it?  Global variables stay black in the editor.  They will not turn blue.  You should be good to go.

If you're running into issues, keep in mind that you global variables are stored as constants in the google scripts editor, and make sure they are uniquely named.  You don't want them to get mixed up with any libraries you might decide to use.  Even if you're not using any libraries, it's good form to put all your global variables in caps or something so they are clearly differentiated from your local variables.